# Anne Pro 2 keyboard won't stay connected via bluetooth with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I tried using the settings panel, blueman-manager and bluetoothctl to connect my keyboard by bluetooth but I always end up with the same result: my keyboard connects and immediately disconnects.
The error message looks like this:

```
[bluetooth]# pair <MAC address>
Attempting to pair with <MAC address>
[CHG] Device <MAC address> Connected: yes
[CHG] Device <MAC address> Connected: no
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled
```

I updated the firmware to the latest version. Been looking around for similar issues but none of the solutions i found worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue for a while, IDK why must Bluetooth be such a pain in Ubuntu. This is what seemed to fix it for me so far.

1. Run `bluetoothctl`
2. Run `agent on`. I don't know what this step quite does, and you can likely skip it.
3. Now, it is possible that some residual connections are messing up the new one. So let's first disconnect the device altogether. Figure out the MAC address of your keyboard or device and do:

```
untrust <mac>
disconnect <mac>
```

4. Make sure this completes successfuly. Now, try `trust <mac>` and then `pair <mac>`. At this point, you may see a verification pin, type it out on the device you are trying to connect (your keyboard) *and press enter*. I did not know that I had to press enter but without it I kept getting errors.
5. At this point, the program should tell you that you are paired but not connected. It is time to connect the paired device, do `connect <mac>`. This should result in a successful pairing.

---

Something else you could try is `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service`. This will restart your bluetooth service. Before trying the above steps, maybe you should close all other bluetooth managers (the GUI based ones) just so we know that nothing else is trying something as we are trying to accomplish a connection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! unfortunately this doesn't work from me: there is no verification pin displayed anywhere...

Comment: Does `bluetoothctl` show any errors at any point of the process mentioned above?

Comment: The same "Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled" after i try to pair.

Comment: When you run `blueman-manager` from the command prompt, it prints out the version number of it, what is that? What does `bluetoothctl --version` get you?

Comment: blueman-manager version 2.1.2, bluetoothctl: 5.53. Thanks a  lot for trying to help by the way!

Comment: I see, run `sudo systemctl status bluetooth` and see if it shows any signs of stress? Otherwise, I'd say uninstall the blueman manager, and purge the bluetoothctl and reinstall it, try the instructions in my answer again and see if that helps? I am sorry, I don't have a better solution. Maybe check that you have all the device related Bluetooth drivers?

Comment: Another thing you should make sure of is that your keyboard is in fact in pairing mode!

Comment: I have tried all that, everything seems okay accordini've tried all 4 g to systemctl, the reinstallation did nothing to help either. I am indeed in pairing mode aha

Comment: Do other Bluetooth devices pair and work?

Comment: yes another keyboard and speakers of mine connect and work fine

Comment: Do any of them ask for a key while pairing?

Comment: i was asked for a pin once with the speaker when i was trying to connect using the settings panel but never again

Comment: @chlotte a little bit late to the party, but I noticed that some of my problems were fixed by simply `sudo apt purge blueman`, i.e., removing Blueman. Try that?

Comment: Hi @scribe ! thanks for your answer but saddly it doesnt work for me

Comment: Same probleme here: Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled

Comment: In fact, simply resetting to factory and following the setup guide solved it for me. Mind that there are 2 functions keystrokes and that FN2 needs to be pressed to enable pairing on the keyboard

Comment: Nothing was working for me in the Kubuntu Bluetooth GUI. I noticed when I pressed FN2-# the number would flash every x/sec but there was a way to hold down FN2-# and get the light to flash 2x/sec, and when it was flashing in that manner... I was able to disconnect, untrust, trust, pair... and voila.